# Как добавить в json = dateTime

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

```
current_datetime = datetime.now().date()

params = {
"range": {
"from": current_datetime,
"to": "2022-12-17",
"timezone": "Europe/Moscow",
"interval": "today"
},
```

TypeError: Object of type date is not JSON serializable

Нужно сделать так чтобы дата была 2022-12-17 формате строго
А то сервер не прочтет
Пробовал готовые классы и т.д ничего не вышло

Comment: "from": f"{current_datetime}"

Comment: Лучший спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

"from": f"{current_datetime}" –

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Приведите весь код с решением